# How to get "Say Ok!Google" text on google search widget

Tags: google, app-widgets, ok-google

I have a samsung galaxy A5 running android 4.4.4. I've seen many kitkat devices having the text "say ok google" on the google search widget in the home screen. How can I get that? It gives the look of a flagship and is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way. I uninstalled the updates of the google app in my device and re-installed the latest version from the play stoore. Then the text appeared. Once I activate ok google detection form "any screen" the text disappears.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly it requires Samsung to enable something. You could try going into the Google app and have a poke around (`settings` -> `voice` -> `OK Google detection`) and see if there's an option there. If not install the Google Now Launcher which does the OK Google from home screen.

[image: Screen one]
[image: Screen 3]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I said the TEXT. just the "Say OK google " TEXT

Comment: @SuryaTeja I knew you said that but I thought that would make it appear. As its still there on my phone...

Answer (score 0):

Text in my widget comes and goes. When it is gone I do this to bring it back: I go into settings and reduce text size. I do not know why it works. I then restore size, and the text remains visible for several days.